# Configuring NGinx to serve static files and proxy pass certain urls

Tags: static, nginx, config

Site is almost completely contained in one html file. All other files may be images, css or javascripts and possibly json files too.

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name git.vosnax.ru;

    location / {
        try_files $uri "/index.html";
        root   /home/sybiam/prod/blog;
        index  index.html;
    }
}
```

This is my current configuration, but this isn't perfect. It will redirect every requests to index.html unless the file exist which is okay.

- <strike>For some reasons, it removes the GET arguments. I'd like to keep them as I can use them within javascript.</strike>

Now, I'd like to add some persistence to the site. Like saving and loading the jsons from a server with really simple auth, it as to support GET and POST. Which means that I can't use `JSONP`.

The question is only on how to configure nginx to forward all requests to let say `/api/*` to my pyramid web server and everything else to index.html unless the file exists.

I could probably host the server on a different domain to make things easier but I have no idea how to handle crossdomain requests. `CORS` isn't supported on old IE.

*EDIT:*
Apparently the query args were always available so it's not a problem anymore. My javascript was overriding the pathname at loadtime and removing the `window.location.search`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the everything else to index.html unless the files exist is the `try_files` bit you have in your `location /`-block already

to pass just the `/api/*` requests to your other server you add the following to your server block (as a sibling of your `location /`-block):

```
location /api/ { 
  proxy_pass http://address_of_server_your_passing_to; 
}
```

see [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) if you want more info on how a request is matched when there's multiple location blocks